# Extraneous elements in "Europe countries" list

Tags: curated-data, geography

I found that the list "Europe countries" encloses "Russia" and "Moldova". This is not correct!
Any hint?

Comment: What exactly is incorrect? Moldova is a European country by every definition I'm aware of, and Russia spans both Europe and Asia. It could easily fit into either list or both.

Comment: [Russia is considered a transcontinental country in both Eastern Europe and Northern Asia. The vast majority of its population (78%) lives in European Russia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe#cnote_b) Moldova is certainly in Europe as well, and it hopes to join the EU in the future.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be more concerned with the inclusion of Svalbard, Jersey, Isle of Man, Gibraltar, Guernsey, and the Faroe Islands on the list as "countries".

Answer (score 11):

You may be looking for `EntityClass["Country", "EuropeanUnion"]` instead.

Otherwise, if you really want to not include Russia and Moldova:

```
countries = Complement[
 Entity["GeographicRegion", "Europe"][
  EntityProperty["GeographicRegion", "Countries"]], {Entity["Country",
    "Russia"], Entity["Country", "Moldova"]}]
```

Now you can still do aggregate computation using `EntityGroup`, such as

```
EntityValue[EntityGroup@countries, "Population"]
```

without including Russia or Moldova. (Alternatively, `Total@EntityValue[countries, "Population"]` will work too.)

You can also do geographic computation:

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon@countries]
```

> [image]

As you can see, Moldova and Russia are not included.